# Java FTC ArrayList and Interface Issues

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make an arraylist of some objects and I've ran into some very weird conundrums. The "objects" we use are of interfaces (not possible), the .add doesn't work (probably because of the first problem), but instanceof works.

This is just the story of how I got here:

I was planning on making a very generalized TeleOp (driver controlled period). You would put the devices in an array list and the sensitivities in another. I used the instanceof keyword to do stuff based on the device type (Servo, CRServo, DcMotor). After that, I went to input it in, and I found that .add(motor) didn't work. It said that it didn't recognize the class of motor. It was initialized as a DcMotor. But, according to this [documentation](https://ftctechnh.github.io/ftc_app/doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/hardware/DcMotor.html), the  DcMotor "class" is actually an interface. Here's another twist. When we set the variable to the actual device, we use this:

```java
fl = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "fl");
fr = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "fr");
bl = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "bl");
br = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "br");
```

What I don't get is the .class part. When I looked that up, it just said that it was the name for the interface. This is the generalized class:

```java
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.Comp_running_code.Comp_Call_Upon_Classes;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.CRServo;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.Gamepad;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.HardwareDevice;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.Servo;

import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.Telemetry;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Commands {
    private double dummy;

    private ArrayList<HardwareDevice> devices = null;
    private ArrayList<Double> sens = null;

    public Commands(ArrayList<HardwareDevice> arrayList, ArrayList<Double> sens){
        devices = arrayList;
        this.sens = sens;
    }
    //High sensitivity value means more input required to move the device
    public static boolean isInRange(double val, double sensitivity){
        if (val<-sensitivity||val>sensitivity){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean isInRange(double val){
        if (val<-.1||val>.1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }



    //Higher sensitivity means that it accepts smaller inputs
    public void run(HardwareDevice thing,Gamepad gamepad, double power, Telemetry telemetry){
        double sensitivity = sens.get(devices.indexOf(thing));

        if (isInRange(power,1-sensitivity)){
            if (thing instanceof DcMotor) {
                ((DcMotor) thing).setPower(power);
                telemetry.addData("Power: ", ((DcMotor) thing).getPower());
            } else if (thing instanceof Servo) {
                ((Servo) thing).setPosition(((Servo) thing).getPosition()+power*sensitivity);
                telemetry.addData("Power: ", ((Servo) thing).getPosition());
            } else if (thing instanceof CRServo) {
                ((CRServo) thing).setPower(power);
                telemetry.addData("Power: ", ((CRServo) thing).getPower());
            } else if (thing instanceof Intake) {
                ((Intake) thing).runIntake(gamepad);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

So I have a few questions:

1. What can I use instead of an arraylist?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's the meaning of "FTC"?

Comment: FTC is the name of the competition my team's in. It stands for First Tech Challenge.

Comment: If FTC is irrelevant, delete. Keep your posts here as concise and on-point as possible.

Comment: Please provide the exact compiler error or runtime exception, not just your summarized understanding of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class, a record, an interface, an annotation type, and an enum type are all defined in a file named with `.java`. And all compile to a file named with `.class`. And all are represented by the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAnnotationPresent(java.lang.Class)) class.

These are all legitimate lines of code:

```
Class<?> c1 = MyClass.class ;
Class<?> c2 = MyInterface.class ;
Class<?> c3 = MyEnum.class ;
Class<?> c4 = MyRecord.class ; 

boolean isInterface = c2.isInterface() ;  // true. 
boolean isEnum = c3.isEnum() ;  // true. 
boolean isRecord = c4.isRecord() ;  // true.
```

> How can an object of an interface exist?

Your [linked Javadoc](https://ftctechnh.github.io/ftc_app/doc/javadoc/com/qualcomm/robotcore/hardware/DcMotor.html) says `DcMotor` is an interface with at least two concrete implementations.

```
DcMotor fl = new DcMotorImpl() ; 
DcMotor bl = new DcMotorImplEx() ;
```

> How do I use an array list or something similar to this?

```
List< DcMotor > motors = List.of ( fl , bl ) ;
```

Or:

```
List< DcMotor > motors = new ArrayList() ;
motors.add( new DcMotorImplEx() ) ;
```

> Would regular arrays work with interfaces?

Yes. You can store instances of any class that implements the interface declared for that array.

```
DcMotor[] motors = { new DcMotorImpl() , new DcMotorImplEx() } ;
```

You commented:

> I've never used the 2 concrete implementations, and neither have I seen anyone on my team use it.

An **interface cannot be instantiated**, [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Somewhere somehow, your team is calling code that instantiates a concrete class implementing that `DcMotor` interface.

One such place might be that line:

```
DcMotor fl = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "fl");
```

Dig deep enough in that `get` method, and you will find some concrete class being instantiated. That instantiation is likely being done through the advanced programming technique of [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). For more info, see correct [Answer here by Luke B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385456/642706).

Comment: Please don't use raw types. Either make that `Class<MyClass> c1` or `Class<?> c1`. Raw types should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @knittl I don’t do much reflection work. What is most appropriate here?

Comment: Either is fine here. Most of the time `Class<?>` is sufficient.

Comment: So, I've never used the 2 concrete implementations, and neither have I seen anyone on my team use it. So the question of how that happens still stands. Do interfaces work with lists? And also, I don't want to use DcMotorImpl or the other one because no one else on my team uses those, and I'm making something for the entire team to use. Thanks, though!

Comment: @mydonut An interface cannot be instantiated. Somewhere in your code a concrete class is being used to instantiate an object, and that class implements your desired interface. As shown in [the other Answer by Luke B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385456/642706), this line seems to be doing that: `DcMotor fl = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "fl");`. If you dig into that `get` method, you'll find somewhere that instantiates an object of a concrete class implementing that interface.

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385200/642706) explains the general idea for interfaces vs classes.

For FTC specifically, you shouldn't construct the `DcMotorImpl` objects yourself. Instead, you should use the hardware map like you are now.

```
DcMotor fl = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "fl");
```

This will get you an instance of some class that implements `DcMotor`. It will already have the information about port number, motor type, etc.

Then you can easily add it to whatever List or array that you want.

```
List<DcMotor> motors = new ArrayList<>();
motors.add(fl);

DcMotor[] motorsArray = new DcMotor[5];
motorsArray[0] = fl;
```

As the documentation says for HardwareMap `get`

> Retrieves the (first) device with the indicated name which is also an instance of the indicated class or interface.

The use of `DcMotor.class` is a kind of [*reflection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) which is a Java feature allowing you to work with classes/types themselves, not just instances of those classes. In this case it is used to get the correct type of device in case of duplicate names in the hardware map, such as a servo called "left" and a DcMotor called "left". It also means you don't need to cast a `HardwareDevice` into a `DcMotor`, it is already returned as that type.